# Trying to export a view but only getting the first line of data repeated

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am trying to export a view using LotusScript.  Some of the columns in the view are displaying multi-value field values which display on separate lines within the view.   I have made some changes to this code that I imported from the web.  I made the change for the separator from commas to pipes "|" because a field in the document may contain commas.

The problem I am having is that I am getting the first line of data to be repeated for the number of entries in the view.

My view looks similar to this:
(For display purposes, I am using commas to separate 3 different items in view)

first column: ReqNum contains

A93120,  A93120,  A94192

second column: Qty contains
1, 16, 10

third column:  Desc contains

tax, APXT918 7" Bolt, 391" sheet metal

The view that I am using is displaying the fields that are needing to be exported.  The second and third column are multi-valued fields.

When I export the view, I get the first item repeated 3 times in the file since the view knows that their are 3 entries within the view.

The exported file will look like this:

|ReqNumber|Qty|Desc

|A93120|1|tax

|A93120|1|tax

|A93120|1|tax

Instead of looking like this:

|ReqNumber|Qty|Desc

|A93120|1|tax

|A93120|16|APXT918 7" Bolt

|A94192|10| 391" sheet metal

Can someone tell me where I am missing the piece to move to the next record in the view?

Thank you in advance for your help.... It is very much appreciated.

Jean Stachler

```
%REM
    Agent Copied Export Code
    Mar 26, 2015 by Jean Stachler
    Description: Comments for Agent
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare
%Include "lsconst.lss"


%REM
    Agent View Export
    Created Mar 27, 2013 by Karl-Henry Martinsson
    Description: Code to export a specified view as CSV.
    Copyright (c) 2013 by Karl-Henry Martinsson
    This code is distributed under the terms of 
    the GNU General Public License V3. 
    See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt
%END REM


Class RowData
    Public column List As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetColumnHeader(view As NotesView)
        Dim viewcolumn As NotesViewColumn
        Dim cnt As Integer
        ForAll vc In view.Columns
            Set viewcolumn = vc
            column(CStr(cnt)) = viewcolumn.Title 
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll  
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetColumnValues(values As Variant)
        Dim cnt As Integer
        Dim tmp As String 
        ForAll v In values
            If IsArray(v) Then
                ForAll c In v
                '    tmp = tmp + c + Chr$(13)
                    tmp = c + Chr$(13)
                    Messagebox tmp
                End ForAll
                column(CStr(cnt)) = Left$(tmp,Len(tmp)-1)
                Messagebox column(CStr(cnt))
            Else
                column(CStr(cnt)) = v 
                Messagebox column(CStr(cnt))
            End If
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll          
    End Sub
End Class

Class CSVData
    Private row List As RowData
    Private rowcnt As Long

    %REM
        Function New
        Description: Open the view and read view data 
        into a list of RowData objects.
    %END REM    
    Public Sub New(server As String, database As String, viewname As String)
        Dim db As NotesDatabase
        Dim view As NotesView
        Dim col As NotesViewEntryCollection
        Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
        Dim colcnt As Integer

        Set db = New NotesDatabase(server, database)
        If db Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not open " + database + " on " + server,16,"Error" 
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set view = db.GetView(viewname)
        If view Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not access view " + viewname + ".",16,"Error" 
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set col = view.AllEntries()
        rowcnt = 0
        Set entry = col.GetFirstEntry()
        Set row("Header") = New RowData()
        Call row("Header").SetColumnHeader(view)
        Do Until entry Is Nothing
            rowcnt = rowcnt + 1
            Set row(CStr(rowcnt)) = New RowData()
            Call row(CStr(rowcnt)).SetColumnValues(entry.ColumnValues)
            Set entry = col.GetNextEntry(entry) 
        Loop
    End Sub

    %REM
        Function CSVArray
        Description: Returns a string array of CSV data by row
    %END REM
    Public Function CSVArray() As Variant
        Dim rowarray() As String 
        Dim textrow As String
        Dim cnt As Long
        ReDim rowarray(rowcnt) As String

        ForAll r In row
            textrow = ""            
            ForAll h In r.column                
                Messagebox h
            '   textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"\n") + |",|
            '   textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"|")
               textrow = textrow + "|" + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"|") 
                Messagebox textrow
            End ForAll
            Messagebox textrow
            rowarray(cnt) = Left$(textrow,Len(textrow)-1)
            Messagebox rowarray(cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll  
        CSVArray = rowarray
    End Function

    %REM
        Function HTMLArray
        Description: Returns a string array of HTML data by row
    %END REM
    Public Function HTMLArray() As Variant
        Dim rowarray() As String 
        Dim textrow As String
        Dim cnt As Long
        ReDim rowarray(rowcnt) As String

        ForAll r In row
            textrow = ""
            ForAll h In r.column 
                textrow = textrow + |<td>| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"<br>") + |</td>|
            End ForAll
            rowarray(cnt) = "<tr>" + textrow + "</tr>"
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll  
        HTMLArray = rowarray
    End Function

End Class


%REM 
     ******************************** 
     Example of how to call the class
     ********************************
%END REM
Sub Initialize
    Dim csv As CSVData
    Dim outfile As String

    Set csv = New CSVData("CrownNotes2/CrownNotes", "Purchasing\purreqdyn.nsf", "(ExportDetail)")
    outfile = "c:\Data\ReqdetailSecond.txt"
    Open outfile For Output As #1
    ForAll row In csv.CSVArray()
        Print #1, row
    End ForAll
    Close #1

    outfile = "c:\Data\ExcelExportTest.xls"
    Open outfile For Output As #2
    Print #2, "<table>"
    ForAll row In csv.HTMLArray()
        Print #2, row
    End ForAll
    Print #2, "</table>"
    Close #2
End Sub
```

Comment: I have just found out that I am not getting the multi-values for the rows.  Instead, I am getting the first value for the multi-value field repeated the number of times the Req Number appears.

Comment: please highlight the part of the code that you have problems with

Comment: It appears that it is in this section where it continues to repeat the line the number of times.

Comment: ForAll r In row
            textrow = ""            
            ForAll h In r.column                
                Messagebox h
            '   textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"\n") + |",|
            '   textrow = textrow + |"| + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"|")
               textrow = textrow + "|" + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"|") 
                Messagebox textrow
            End ForAll
            Messagebox textrow
            rowarray(cnt) = Left$(textrow,Len(textrow)-1)
            Messagebox rowarray(cnt)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End ForAll  
        CSVArray = rowarray

Answer (score 0):

I will try again to get the details listed.
Here is the section that will repeat the line the number of times the line is listed.  It seems to me that it is picking up the first item, instead of going through the multivalue field.

ForAll r In row

```
        textrow = ""            
        ForAll h In r.column                
            Messagebox h
            textrow = textrow + "|" + Replace(h,Chr$(13),"|") 
            Messagebox textrow
        End ForAll
        Messagebox textrow
        rowarray(cnt) = Left$(textrow,Len(textrow)-1)
        Messagebox rowarray(cnt)
        cnt = cnt + 1

    End ForAll  
    CSVArray = rowarray
```

I have also come up with another way of doing this but am having a problem trying to get rid of carriage returns.  Will post this issue shortly.